# ASP.NET MVC Display HTML Based on User Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Following best practices, is there a better way to show/hide controls based on the user's role, or is it perfectly acceptable to use **User.IsInRole()** inside of a view? An answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194258/asp-net-mvc-4-how-do-you-serve-different-html-based-on-role) says it violates separation of concerns. What are the alternatives?

```html
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "Games")
}

<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Home</th>
            <th scope="col">Away</th>
            <th scope="col">Field</th>
            <th scope="col">Result</th>
            @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <th scope="col"></th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var g in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <th>@g.GameDate</th>
            <th>@g.HomeTeam.TeamName</th>
            <th>@g.AwayTeam.TeamName</th>
            <th><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=directions to @g.Ballpark.Street @g.Ballpark.City @g.Ballpark.StateId" target="_blank">@g.Ballpark.Name</a></th>
            <th>(@g.HomeTeamRuns-@g.AwayTeamRuns) @g.Result</th>
            @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <th> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = g.GameId })</th>
            }
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If i were you, i would make separate views for user and admins, as this is a principle in SOLID principles, just to reduce the if statements in project and if want to make a change for admin or user only then this will make sense for you, hope i helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would add a bool property to the model `IsAdmin` and set the value in the controller. That way your View is only working with the Model.

```
@if (Model.IsAdmin)
{
    // render admin elements
}
```

Comment: So the code would essentially remain the same, but rather than calling User.IsInRole(), i would check the Model.IsAdmin property of my model?

Comment: Yes. It looks like your current model is a list of some sort. Move this into a separate Model class where you can add additional properties like 'IsAdmin'.