# Generic way to hide ActionLinks by checking Access Right

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written a custom filter attribute to check against every controller action, if user has right to access that action i give access otherwise i redirect to controller Unauthorized Access, here is my code:

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

        if (!CheckAccessRight(actionName, controllerName))
        {
            string redirectUrl = string.Format("?returnUrl={0}", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + redirectUrl, true);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my CheckAccessRight Method:

```
private bool CheckAccessRight(string Action, string Controller)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"] != null)
    {
        string userID = HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"].ToString();
        using (var db = new cloud_clinicEntities())
        {
            assignment objAss = db.assignments.SingleOrDefault(model => model.userid == userID);

            String UserRole = objAss.itemname;

            itemchildren objChild = db.itemchildrens.SingleOrDefault(model => model.parent == UserRole && model.child == Controller + " " + Action);

            if (objChild != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

now i want on my each view if there is action link to a controller action which user has no right to access it should not be rendered on page or it should be hidden. How to do that in generic way, i have idea that i can do by adding if statement on each Action Link but i don't think its better approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Role-Based Content asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928654/role-based-content-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an HTML Helper, which is kind of extension to normal ActionLink, but it takes one more argument which is Role string as shown below. [Credit goes to Eu-ge-ne for his original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928654/role-based-content-asp-net-mvc/929336#929336)

```
public static class Html
{
    public static string RoleActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string role, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        return html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(role)
            ? html.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName)
            : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: but what about if i have some anchor tags like this:
<a href="@Url.Action("Action","Controller")" >Link </a>

how i deal with this also?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad How many anchor links you have on your page, if you are talking specifically for Menu, then you can have security trimming menu in MVC. But if you are talking about random links on entire pages, then I am afraid you have to either go with custom Helper or If conditions. If this requirement is to show/hide some links on tabular data, then I would simply go with Html Helper because it is easy to maintain.

Comment: can you share some sample code on that i need to hide some random links on my page, i had written custom action filter and user is to able to view the page but requirement is to hide it as well if its not in its rights

Comment: @EhsanSajjad you can change those anchor tags to custom RoleActionLink() as shown above right?

Comment: i am writing like this : 
<a href="@Url.Action("Action","Controller")" >Link </a>
Can i write Custom Url Extension, if yes, how?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `this UrlHelper url` for example :-)

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928654/role-based-content-asp-net-mvc?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I have given credit to the original author in my answer. Also I posted the code snippet, just because if the original question got deleted, then there would be a reference of code in here. Hope I never did anything wrong.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. If the answer from another question answers this question, then perhaps this question is a duplicate of the other. So I ask, how is this question _not_ a duplicate of the other?